# Spark performance tuning for the cartesianproduct

Tags: performance, apache-spark

I want to do join two datasets ,first dataset is with 4.5 GB and second dataset is with 5MB.

Below is my query ,

```
val data= rdd1.join(rdd2,regexp_replace($"rdd2.SUBSCRIBER_ID","^0*","") === regexp_replace($"rdd1.subscriberid","^0*", "" ) or
    ((substring($"rdd2.FIRST_NAME",0,3) === $"rdd1.firstName") and (substring($"rdd2.LAST_NAME",0,4) === $"rdd1.lastName") and (regexp_replace(substring($"rdd2.BIRTH_DATE",0,10),"-","") === $"rdd1.DOB")) or
    ((substring($"rdd2.FIRST_NAME",0,3) === $"rdd1.firstName") and (substring($"rdd2.LAST_NAME",0,4) === $"rdd1.lastName")  and ($"rdd2.GENDER" === $"rdd1.gender")) or 
    ((substring($"rdd2.FIRST_NAME",0,3) === $"rdd1.firstName") and (regexp_replace(substring($"rdd2.BIRTH_DATE",0,10),"-","") === $"rdd1.DOB") and ($"rdd2.GENDER" === $"rdd1.gender")) or 
    ((substring($"rdd2.LAST_NAME",0,4) === $"rdd1.lastName") and (regexp_replace(substring($"rdd2.BIRTH_DATE",0,10),"-","") === $"rdd1.DOB") and ($"rdd2.GENDER" === $"rdd1.gender")))
```

It is running as Cartesian join, Used broadcast for rdd2 ,but there is no performance.

I am using these properties.

```
--num-executors 30 --driver-memory 12G --executor-memory 30G  --executor-cores 6

--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=2001 --conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer 
--conf spark.cleaner.ttl=800 --conf spark.debug.maxToStringFields=1000
```

We do have 300 vcores availability.

How can I change my query to get the better performance

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: Could you show us the result of data.explain?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the shuffle partition configuration and keep the cores only to 2-4.

Please try and let me know the result.

Comment: Still it is same and the job stuck at one place from 40 min.
[Stage 5:======================================================>(398 + 2) / 400]

Comment: What is the data source whether it’s from HDFS or from any rdbms. Data skewedness can also be a problem. Can you please show your sample data and what exactly you want to achieve out of this join. Then I can suggest if there is anything wrong in the sql

Comment: Data is in HDFS.In rdd1 I have 5 columns out of them one column is with 2KB size,I am comparing first 4 columns ,if they matches(condition as above mentioned) then I am writing the 5 th column to output.(I am sorry that I cannot share any data )

Comment: I see the same redundant join conditions multiple times for the same columns. Please remove it and try

Comment: But we do have a req like ,from 4 conditions any of 3 satisfies we should write that line to output

Comment: Ok please try to remove and have only one condition and see the performance. Wanted to drill down to the exact cause as I cannt play with the live data.

Comment: Thanks @Chandan, It worked well. Removed "OR" condition ,created multiple dataframes  and did the union all.

Comment: Cool then. Let me know if you need any help in this

Answer (score 0):

Removed "OR" condition ,created multiple dataframes and did the union all

```
val data= rdd1.join(rdd2,regexp_replace($"rdd2.SUBSCRIBER_ID","^0*","") === regexp_replace($"rdd1.subscriberid","^0*", "" )) 
val data1 = rdd1.join(rdd2,((substring($"rdd2.FIRST_NAME",0,3) === $"rdd1.firstName") and (substring($"rdd2.LAST_NAME",0,4) === $"rdd1.lastName") and (regexp_replace(substring($"rdd2.BIRTH_DATE",0,10),"-","") === $"rdd1.DOB")))
val data2 = rdd1.join(rdd2,((substring($"rdd2.FIRST_NAME",0,3) === $"rdd1.firstName") and (substring($"rdd2.LAST_NAME",0,4) === $"rdd1.lastName")  and ($"rdd2.GENDER" === $"rdd1.gender")))
val data3 =  rdd1.join(rdd2,((substring($"rdd2.FIRST_NAME",0,3) === $"rdd1.firstName") and (regexp_replace(substring($"rdd2.BIRTH_DATE",0,10),"-","") === $"rdd1.DOB") and ($"rdd2.GENDER" === $"rdd1.gender")))
val data4= rdd1.join(rdd2,((substring($"rdd2.LAST_NAME",0,4) === $"rdd1.lastName") and (regexp_replace(substring($"rdd2.BIRTH_DATE",0,10),"-","") === $"rdd1.DOB") and ($"rdd2.GENDER" === $"rdd1.gender")))

val finaldata = data union data1 union data2 union data3 union data4
```

Comment: what about any explanation?

Comment: added explanation